# Are custom url schemes different for tvos apps on Apple TV vs. iOS apps (netflix, youtube, hbogo)?

Tags: tvos, deep-linking, apple-tv

I am working on an apple tv app where I am trying to deeplink to specific pages within other third party apps. I see the way to open the other app is to use its url scheme however most url schemes that work in ios are not working on tvos.

So far, I've found a couple that work on tvos (netflix, abc). However the following url schemes which work on ios are not opening the app on tvos - Youtube (youtube://), showtime anytime (shoany://), DailyMotion (dailymotion//). In some cases the url scheme opens the app but the full deeplink doesn't navigate to the correct page (ex. hbogo).

Do anyone know if the url schemes used by tvos apps is different from ios? Also is there any way to extract the url scheme of the tvos version of the app?

Comment: I'm pretty sure this all comes down to each vendor's implementation of their tvos app.  Your best bet is probably to contact each one individually.

Comment: For example, that HBOGO's TV app doesn't navigate to the correct page while the iOS app does is going to come down to code that they have written and you won't be able to do anything about.

Comment: Okay thanks for the clarification. Is there a way to at least get the url scheme needed to open the app? I know with ios you can do this from the .ipa but not sure with tvos apps.

Comment: Did you find anything about Youtube or Netflix. It seems that companies are trying to avoid the implementation of URL Scheme

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if you already found your answer but for the sake if visibility:

right now showtime uses different urlschemes for their tvOS apps than the one they use on iOS. The urlschemes used are:

```
com.showtime://
com.showtimeanytime://
```

I expect them to change these to be the same as the iOS apps so make sure to be able to support both varieties.

Comment: Working on tvos. from where you get the scheme?

Thanks

Comment: I tried "com.showtime://play/51320" to play video of showtime on AppleTV, it is saying The Server Is Not Available.

Comment: Showtime doesn't use slashes in their deeplink urls
Try `com.showtime:episode:51320`